# On the determination of $\#Hom(D_m, \mathbb Z_n)$ if $m$ is odd

Tags: abstract-algebra

Please help me to find it.

We are willing to search for number of group homomorphisms from $D_m$ to $\mathbb Z_n$ where $m$ is odd and $n\in \mathbb N$.

Now any group homomorphism $\rho: D_m\rightarrow \mathbb Z_n$ is completely determined by image of $\rho(r), \rho(f)$ where we are assuming 
$$D_m:=\{r, f: r^m=f^2=(rf)^2=e\}$$

Since $\rho$ is group homomorphism so $|\rho(r)|$ must divide $|r|$ as well as $|\mathbb Z_n|$ i.e. $|\rho(r)|$ divides $(m, n)$. If we denote the number of elements of order $d$ in group $G$ as $\eta_d(G)$ then for $\rho(r)$ we are getting $\sum\limits_{d|(m,n)}\eta_d(\mathbb Z_n)$ possibilities.

Similarly for  $\rho(f)$ we shall get $\sum\limits_{d|(2, n)}\eta_d(\mathbb Z_n)$ possibilities.

So altogether we shall get

$\#Hom(D_m, \mathbb Z_n)=\sum\limits_{d|(m,n)}\eta_d(\mathbb Z_n)\times \sum\limits_{d|(2,n)}\eta_d(\mathbb Z_n)=\sum\limits_{d|(m,n)}\varphi(d)\sum\limits_{d|2}\varphi(2)=2(m,n)$.

Am I correct in my calculation ?>

Comment: Your computation is wrong, because it's not true that picking an element $f' \in D_m$ s.t. $f'^2 = 1$ and an element $r' \in D_m$ s.t. $r'^m = 1$ will give you a morphism $D_m \to \mathbb Z/n$: you're forgetting that $f$ and $r$ are linked by the $(rf)^2 = 1$ relation, so $r'$ and $f'$ cannot be chosen independently.

Comment: Do you know the morphisms from the symmetric group $\mathfrak S(m)$ to a cyclic group $\mathbb Z/n$?

Comment: If you look at my answer to your previous question this problem is easy. I guess I'll write an answer to this one.

Comment: So in other words, if we find the choice of $r, f$  are satisfying $(r'f')^2=0$, should we consider those as correct choice ?

Comment: Please ! I would be obliged . Right now I am completely confused how shall I fiinish it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any homomorphism $D_m\to \mathbb{Z}_n$ factors through the abelianization of $D_m$, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$. The easiest way to construct the homomorphism is by considering $D_m$ to be generated by two reflections $s_1,s_2$. If $n$ is odd, then $f(s_1)=f(s_2)=0$ because there is no element of order $2$. This is also a possible homomorphism if $n$ is even, but there is also an additional homomorphism with $f(s_1)=f(s_2)=n/2$.

Comment: Let me say some thing here please. From your comment on the previous post, it seems like $Hom(D_m, \mathbb Z_n)$ is same as $Hom(\mathbb Z_2, \mathbb Z_n)$ when $m$ is odd and $Hom(D_m, \mathbb Z_n)$ is same as $Hom(\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2, \mathbb Z_n)$ when $m$ is even. Am I right ? Then the answer should be $(2, n)$ or $(2, n)^2$ according as $m$ is odd or even.

Comment: @Anjan3 If you're using that notation for gcd, then I believe that is correct.

Comment: yes sir. I used that notation for gcd only. Thank you for your kind help. between, may I ask you one last question please? Is it true that $D_{2n}$ is isomorphic to the group $D_n\times \mathbb Z_2$ for any $n\in \mathbb N$? Or there is some extra condition we need on $n$ ?

Comment: @Anjan3 I don't believe that's ever true (too commutative). Usually $D_{2n}$ is just used as an alternate notation for $D_n$.

Comment: @Anjan3 I'm not completely certain though.